# Best way to mask a single bit in AVX2?

Tags: c, x86, simd, avx, avx2

For example, with an input `ymm` vector `x` and bit index `i` I want an output vector with only the `i`th bit kept and everything else zeroed.

With AVX512 `k` registers, I could write the following, but AVX2 and below doesn't have `k` registers, so what do you think is the best way to do it?

```
__m512i m512i_maskBit(__m512i x, unsigned i) {
    __mmask8 m = _cvtu32_mask8(1u << i / 64);
    __m512i vm = _mm512_maskz_set1_epi64(m, 1ull << i % 64);
    return _mm512_and_si512(x, vm);
}
```

Comment: Untested: Broadcast `i` to a register, subtract offsets `[0, 32, ..., 224]` then `vpsllvd` a vector of `1`s.

Comment: @chtz If `i = 0`, `[0, 0, ..., 0] - [0, 32, ..., 224] = [0, -32, ..., -224] = [0, 0xffffffe0, ..., 0xffffff20]`. Left-shifting this vector by `1` doesn't produce the correct mask, or did I misunderstand your sentence?

Comment: I now made an answer based on my comment. Hope that clarifies what I meant ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an approach using variable shifts (just creating the mask):

```
__m256i create_mask(unsigned i) {
    __m256i ii = _mm256_set1_epi32(i);
    ii = _mm256_sub_epi32(ii,_mm256_setr_epi32(0,32,64,96,128,160,192,224));
    __m256i mask = _mm256_sllv_epi32(_mm256_set1_epi32(1), ii);
    return mask;
}
```

`_mm256_sllv_epi32` (`vpsllvd`) was introduced by AVX2 and it shifts each 32 bit element by a variable amount of bits. If the (unsigned) shift-amount is bigger than 31 (i.e., also for signed negative numbers), the corresponding result is 0.

Godbolt link with small test code: https://godbolt.org/z/a5xfqTcGs

Comment: Regarding your analysis: If you would run this in a hot loop, at least the generation of the `_mm256_set1_epi32(1)` vector should be done outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the flaw.. I think these static analyzers are giving me more headaches to do it correctly. I also noticed that your version has only 1 broadcast dependent on `i`, so it makes your code run faster in a hot loop where `i` changes every iteration.

Comment: I put your code in a loop with `i` incrementing and extracted the relevant assembly to put in a static analyzer. Do you think this [result](https://uica.uops.info/tmp/d32eace048194d939734ecc3cdd73728_trace.html) makes sense? The vectors with constant values are preloaded outside the loop.

Comment: If you increment `i` every iteration, you could also add `_mm256_set1_epi32(1)` directly to `ii` (saving the broadcast). If `i` was loaded from memory you could do a broadcast from memory (which does not need p5 on Intel CPUs). Short summary: Try to benchmark your actual code. Creating meaningful micro-benchmarks is not trivial.

Answer (score 2):

How about the simplest approach:

```
__m256i m256i_create_mask(unsigned i) {
    // Get the required bit in every byte of the vector
    __m256i vm = _mm256_broadcastb_epi8(_mm_cvtsi32_si128(1u << (i & 7u)));
    // Mask off the bytes that are outside the index
    __m256i vi = _mm256_broadcastb_epi8(_mm_cvtsi32_si128(i >> 3u));
    __m256i vm1 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(vi,
        _mm256_setr_epi8(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
            16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31));
    return _mm256_and_si256(vm, vm1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here’s another approach. Not sure it’s necessarily better, it depends on CPU model and surrounding code, but it might be.

```
// A buffer to load vectors with a single bit set in one lane
alignas( 64 ) static const std::array<int, 16> s_oneBuffer =
{
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
};

__m256i maskSingleBit( __m256i x, uint32_t bitIndex )
{
    // Load `1` into a single 32-bit lane of the vector
    // The buffer aligned by 64 bytes, contained in a single cache line, no unaligned load penalty.
    __m256i one = _mm256_loadu_si256( ( const __m256i* )( ( s_oneBuffer.data() + 8 ) - ( bitIndex / 32 ) ) );

    // Left shift to move the `1` into the correct location
    __m128i shift = _mm_cvtsi32_si128( bitIndex % 32 );
    __m256i bit = _mm256_sll_epi32( one, shift );

    // Bitwise AND with the value
    return _mm256_and_si256( x, bit );
}
```

Comment: Interesting! Before the final `and` and only considering the code dependent on `i`, the currently accepted answer is basically `movd->broadcast->sub->sll` and yours is `movdqu|movd->sll`, where `movdqu` and `movd` can happen at the same time. I'll have a look later, but I think this is very promising.

Comment: I was hoping yours to be fastest, but unfortunately the index calculation `buf + 8 - i / 32` is quite an overhead. I extracted the relevant assembly from the compiled output of your code in a loop with `i` incrementing, and put it in a static analyzer.

Comment: [This](https://uica.uops.info/tmp/183523b553794e3a90072fc030c18f83_trace.html) is the result. You can see that `movdqu` is executed several cycles later wating for the index calculation. You can compare it with the [result](https://uica.uops.info/tmp/d32eace048194d939734ecc3cdd73728_trace.html) for another approach.